# Prefix Operator Strangeness in C++ and array indices

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

So I just ran into a huge headache with the prefix operator.

In my debug build in Visual C++ 2010.

```
someArray[++index]
```

Would correctly increment the array index and then use it to index into the array.

In my release build it used the array index and then incremented it afterwards, causing some huge headaches.

The weird thing is my debug build code was actually wrong for a while and I had it written as

```
someArray[index++]
```

This would use the index and then increment it, but the debug build was still incrementing it, and then using the value.  I didn't even realize my mistake until this morning.

Here's a sample of the actual code.

```
for(unsigned int newPointIndex = 0; newPointIndex < newEdgeList.size() - 1;) {
    m_edges.push_back(Edge(newEdgeList[newPointIndex], newEdgeList[++newPointIndex]));
}
```

There is no incrementing happening in the for loop.  It happens in the actual code inside the loop while I'm indexing into the array.  I thought it was a clever little optimization, but it makes it not work in the release build.

The second time I was indexing into the array, it was using the unincremented index in the release build, but was working in the debug build.

Comment: I doubt that. It shouldn't matter whether it's release or debug. I think you were just testing it poorly. You can't rely on the debugger in release builds.

Comment: There is no way that debug vs. release builds are changing language-defined operator semantics.  Is there some more information you can share?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, the debugger still works on optimized code, it just might not track well with the source code.  If you step through the assembly, you should still see reasonable behaviour.

Comment: @CarlNorum isn't that what I said (i.e. can't rely on it)?

Comment: Well I could post a bigger part of the code.

It was actually part of a for loop.

I edited the question to include a sample.

Comment: Please put that code in your question, not in a comment.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, maybe we mean different things by "rely".  I think I see what you were getting at.  I use the debugger to inspect optimized code all the time, and it's an indispensable tool.  It's just that you have to be a bit more careful watching what's going on.

Comment: the problem is that you cannot guarantee the order of evaluation of those two sub-expressions

Comment: Your `for` loop is missing a `;`, so I don't really think this is your real code.  That said, @Andy has the right answer.

Answer (score 6):

Your for loop body includes this:

```
Edge(newEdgeList[newPointIndex], newEdgeList[++newPointIndex])
```

That's <strike>undefined</strike> <strike>unspecified</strike> undefined [1] behaviour, because the two arguments can be evaluated in either order (or even simultaneously), so it's not clear whether `newPointIndex` will have been incremented or not before the first use.

Debug and optimized builds are very likely to evaluate arguments in different orders.

I'd suggest putting the `newPointIndex` increment in the for statement itself, and writing in the body:

```
Edge(newEdgeList[newPointIndex], newEdgeList[newPointIndex + 1])
```

---

[1]: Read the comments for the discussion of un{specified, defined}. tl;dr: Holy leaping lizards, Batman!

Comment: Yeah, now that I think about it, this makes sense.  I've ran into a similar problem before when I was reading from a stream, but doing the reading inside the function call itself as an argument instead of creating a temporary variable to read into and passing that as an argument.

Comment: I don't think that is Undefined Behavior (which means an implementation is actually free to do *anything*), just undefined order of execution (which means an implementation is just free to reorder the evaluation of those two expressions)...

Comment: This is one of the reasons that I try to avoid using either increment operator in the middle of an expression, except when the behavior of a post-increment would be obvious based on popular idioms (e.g. `container.remove(it++)`). Tricky code is unmaintainable code, so I'd suggest using the increment operators as standalone statements only, except when there is a *really* compelling reason not to.

Comment: Andy is right. It's only unspecified what order the arguments are evaluated in.

Comment: @AndyProwl: quite right, I changed it to unspecified. It's only undefined if there are two unsequenced mutations.

Comment: @AndyProwl: it is undefined behavior. The wording in C++03 is 5/4, "Between the previous and next sequence point a scalar object shall have its stored value modified at most once ... the prior value shall be accessed only to determine the value to be stored. The requirements of this paragraph shall be met for each allowable ordering of the subexpressions of a full expression; otherwise the behavior is undefined". There is an allowable ordering of this code that accesses `newPointIndex` other than in order to determine the value to be stored by `++newPointIndex`, with no sequence point.

Comment: C++11 defines things differently, it's all "sequenced before" and "indeterminately sequenced" rather than sequence points and unspecified order of execution. I believe there's still an UB criterion in there somewhere, though.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I am trying to find that in the C++11 standard, and there is indeed something similar (1.9/15): *"If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either another side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined"*. That seems to be specific for "evaluations of operands of individual operators". Does it apply to our case?

Comment: @AndyProwl: I don't think it is specific. It follows a statement that "evaluations of operands of individual operators" are unsequenced, but it applies to side-effects and computations in general, not only those that are part of the operands of a common operator. So I think you've found the C++11 equivalent of my C++03 quotation, thank you. In our case, `++newPointIndex` has a side-effect, and is unsequenced with the value computation `newPointIndex` in the other argument expression.

Comment: @AndyProwl: aha! ok, restored the answer to undefined. In practice, I don't think it makes much difference; undefined or unspecified, the function call is just plain incorrect.

Answer (score 5):

The **problem** is actually here:

```
m_edges.push_back(Edge(newEdgeList[newPointIndex], newEdgeList[++newPointIndex]));
```

You cannot tell which of the two expressions `newEdgeList[newPointIndex]` and `newEdgeList[++newPointIndex]` is going to be executed first.

According to the C++ Standard, there is **no guarantee** that they will be executed left-to-right. See 5.2.2/8:

*"The evaluations of the postfix expression and of the argument expressions are all **unsequenced
relative to one another**. All side effects of argument expression evaluations are sequenced before the function is entered"*

Also relevant is 1.9/15:

*"When calling a function (whether or not the function is inline), every value computation and side effect associated with any argument expression, or with the postfix expression designating the called function, is sequenced before execution of every expression or statement in the body of the called function. [ Note: Value computations and side effects associated with different argument expressions are unsequenced. —end note ]"*

This means that an implementation is free *not only* to have a different order of execution of those two expressions in debug to release build, but in theory also to change the order every time you execute that statement *in the same program execution and in no deterministic way*.

The **solution** consists in taking the increment out of those sub-expressions (as pointed out in another answer).